# Adding clauses directly to the z3 solver

Tags: c++, c, z3, sat

I have an AIG (and-inverter graph) which I keep modifying and whose satisfiability I need to check in an incremental manner using Z3.  I can  generate a CNF representation of the AIG and  would ideally like to feed these clauses directly to the solver and call it repeatedly from my code.  Is there some way that I can directly add clauses (or an AIG) to Z3 solver through C/C++ APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simply assert new assertions, which are internally translated into clauses.

Note that for many incremental solving problems, Z3 does not use an off-the-shelf, dedicated SAT-solver, but it's own SMT solver that incorporates some of the features of SAT solvers, but not all, and which natively handles non-Boolean problems. So, it's not necessarily the case that hacking the solver to inject clauses directly will translate into significantly improved performance.

Z3 also has a dedicated Boolean-only SAT solver and if you're solving purely Boolean problems, this solver is likely much faster. You can force it to use this solver by replacing `(check-sat)` with `(check-sat-using sat)`, or by running the tactic called 'sat'. The implementation of this solver is in [sat_solver.h/.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/sat/sat_solver.h), which would be the prime place to start looking around, if you'd like to hack it.

Z3 also uses it's own implementation of AIGs as a pre-processing step in some tactics, see [aig_tactic.h/.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/tactic/aig/aig_tactic.h).